# Simplify two MySQL queries by merging them into 1?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL queries which are very similiar however they return a `COUNT()` upon a specific `WHERE` clause (`type`), so I was wondering if they could be merged into 1 query seeing as only the `WHERE` clause (`type`) differenciates the two?

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(referral_id) AS in_count
FROM   referrals
WHERE  author = '{$author}'
       AND type = 'in'
       AND ip_address = '{$ip_address}'
LIMIT  1
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(referral_id) AS out_count
FROM   referrals
WHERE  author = '{$author}'
       AND type = 'out'
       AND ip_address = '{$ip_address}'
LIMIT  1
```

All help is greatly appreciated :B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(type='in',1,0)) as in_count, 
       SUM(IF(type='out',1,0)) as out_count
FROM   referrals
WHERE  author = '{$author}' AND
       ip_address = '{$ip_address}'
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: +1, was just typing this up but beat me to it. To the OP, [this MySQL tidbit](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/page3.html) may be of some help for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(referral_id) AS count, type
FROM   referrals
WHERE  author = '{$author}'
   AND ip_address = '{$ip_address}'
GROUP BY type
LIMIT  1
```